# Multiple nested queries to count total of each category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask for any suggestions on how to do the following on SQL Server

The required output columns would be

```
EmpName | CompleteCalls | IncompleteCalls
```

which basically counts each Employee's number of Complete Calls and Incomplete Calls

the current table structure is like this

```
EmpName | Flag
```

the flag in bit data type that represents either a Complete call or Incomplete call. An Employee's name can repeat in different rows for each type of Call.
For example, an employee can have both flags of Complete and Incomplete Calls in 2 rows.

Now how do I do this in SQL Server? So far I have tried the following:

```
select EmpName, 
          (select count(*) 
             from call_log 
            where flag = 1 
              and EmpName in (select EmpName 
                                from call_log 
                               where flag = 1)  ) AS  [CompleteCalls] 
     FROM call_log
```

but as you may notice, the query result is not accurate since each Employee will get the total count of complete calls currently on the table.

TIA

Comment: What's the expected behavior when an employee has 2 rows, one a completed call and the other incompleted call?

Comment: it will just be as is. The employee can have both complete call and incomplete call in different rows. Its just a record table of how many complete and incomplete call an employee has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT EmpName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN 1 ElSE 0 END) AS COMPLETECALLS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 0 THEN 1 ElSE 0 END) AS INCOMPLETECALLS
FROM call_log
GROUP BY EmpName
```

It will SUM 1 for each row in the table that has flag = 1 or flag = 0 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN Complete=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumComplete
, SUM(CASE WHEN Complete=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumIncomplete
, EmpName
FROM call_log
GROUP BY EmpName
```